# Can gdb print expanded preprocessor/macro results?

Tags: gdb, c-preprocessor, preprocessor, debug-information

For example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define A 20
#define B 22
#define C (A+B)

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int i = (rand()&1) + C;
    return i;
}
```

In gdb,

```
(gdb) print C
No symbol "C" in current context.
```

How can I know what `C` is? Can `gdb` tell me? (I added `rand()` so we can't easily deduce what it was)

The preprocessor will have replaced C with `(20+22)`. Is this value available in the debuginfo to print somehow?

In a real example where the macro could be exceedingly complex, I don't want to waste my time doing the job of the preprocessor.

Comment: If you compile with with gcc and pass `-g3` option (for level 3 debugging information) you will have all the macro definitions present in the program. The default is debugging level (with just `-g` is level 2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I know what C is?

First of all you need to build the program with `-g3` flag so that macro information is included in debugging information, start the program and show macro definition with `info macro`:

```
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x40114e: file 1.c, line 9.
Starting program: /tmp/a.out 
Missing separate debuginfos, use: dnf debuginfo-install glibc-2.31-4.fc32.x86_64

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at 1.c:9
9       srand(time(0));
(gdb) info macro C
Defined at /tmp/1.c:5
#define C (A+B)
(gdb) info macro A
Defined at /tmp/1.c:3
#define A 20
(gdb) info macro B
Defined at /tmp/1.c:4
#define B 22
```

You can also expand macro:

```
(gdb) macro expand C
expands to: (20+22)
```